# HeadlessUI React, how to detect currently focused element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, headless-ui

I'm trying to build a funky use case:

I have a HeadlessUI dialog, inside this dialog, there is a HeadlessUI Menu component as a nested child, I want to trigger the menu via a keyboard shortcut

I have managed to trigger the dialog, via:

```
// I took the useWindowEvent from the headlessUI code
useWindowEvent("keydown", (event) => {
    if (event.key === "p") {
      event.preventDefault()
      event.stopPropagation()
      selectorRef.current?.click()
    }
  })
```

and on my Menu component:

```
// My react component forwardRefs to the trigger button
export const ProjectSelector = forwardRef(
... some other component code
<Menu.Button ref={ref} as="div">
... other code
```

This works fine to trigger the Menu, but the menu also has a search bar, so whenever I press the p key, the listener triggers again and programmatically closes the Menu

I have taken a look inside the headlessUI code trying to understand the focus trap code, but it's above my head, is there any way to detect if the parent Dialog has focus? that way I can just ignore the keypress if focus is on the menu :)

Workaround:

While writing the question I stumbled upon a workaround... it is not super pretty, so maybe someone can come up with a better solution:

```
  // I'm pretty sure I'm doing everything wrong in here
  // but I couldn't find another way to remotely trigger and keep focus on the menu component
  useWindowEvent("keydown", (event) => {
    if (
      event.key === "p" &&
      document.activeElement?.getAttribute("role") !== "menu" &&
      document.activeElement?.tagName !== "INPUT"
    ) {
      event.preventDefault()
      event.stopPropagation()
      selectorRef.current?.click()
    }
  })
```

Comment: What do you mean by trigger? Open & close or search the values ?

Comment: trigger = open and close, and then the problem comes when searching the values

Comment: can you create reproducible example?